# Linq query where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am using `Linq to Entities` and I have a query something like this

```
context.Hotels
        .Where(h => h.HotelType.Contains(s.HotelTypeId.ToString()))
        .Select(hotel => new Model.Hotel
           {
              HotelId = hotel.HotelID,
              HotelName = hotel.HotelName,
              HotelFileName = hotel.HotelFileName,
              StarRating = hotel.StarRating,
              CountryName = hotel.Country.CountryName,
              PlaceName = hotel.Place.PlaceName
           })
```

I am using `.ToString()` in `where` clause which I know is not valid when work with `Linq To Entities`. But actually "HotelType" column have values separated with pipe characters like 1|2|3..Now I want to extract only those Hotels that have a type 1..How is it possible? Please help

Comment: First of all, you must change your tables structure. It is not good to save `1|2|3` in one cell. You can create another table with the name `HotelTypes` with at least two columns: `Hotel_ID` and `Type_ID`. Then use  join to this table.

Comment: I have a very large database, it is quite difficult at this moment. I am wondering if somehow i can make it possible

Comment: Consider making the question title more specific. This one is really not describing your problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hack but it should work.

```
Where(h => ("|" + h.HotelType + "|").Contains("|" + s.HotelTypeId.ToString() + "|"))
```

It first turns `1|2|3` into `|1|2|3|` and then looks for `|1|` or `|2|` and will work no matter if the ID is first or last or somewhere in the middle.

But you really should restructure your database - it is usually a very bad idea to have information encoded like that and you already found out because you had to ask how to do something that should be trivial.

Comment: I am getting this error now: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Add back the `ToString()` call - I thought you can leave it out but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that ToString() is supported in EF 6.1
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Hotels
    .Where(h => h.HotelType.Split('|').Select(str=>Convert.ToInt32(str)).Contains(s.HotelTypeId))
    .Select(hotel => new Model.Hotel
       {
          HotelId = hotel.HotelID,
          HotelName = hotel.HotelName,
          HotelFileName = hotel.HotelFileName,
          StarRating = hotel.StarRating,
          CountryName = hotel.Country.CountryName,
          PlaceName = hotel.Place.PlaceName
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `HotelType` is `int` you can do this.

```
context.Hotels
    .Where(h => h.HotelType.Split("|").Select(ht=>int.Parse(ht))
    .Contains(s.HotelTypeId))
    .Select(hotel => new Model.Hotel
       {
          HotelId = hotel.HotelID,
          HotelName = hotel.HotelName,
          HotelFileName = hotel.HotelFileName,
          StarRating = hotel.StarRating,
          CountryName = hotel.Country.CountryName,
          PlaceName = hotel.Place.PlaceName
       });
```